# Copy complex table using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I writing a stored procedure to copy rows in a table.

This is the table

[image: Example]

I want to copy this but the ParentId should be linked to the new row.
If i do a simple INSERT INTO > SELECT FROM the ParentId will be linked to the ProductId 22 not the new ProductId as you can see above.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: do you wish to copy single row at a time or whole table?? Most probably I think its whole table right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear, but if I understand it correctly, you are trying to copy several rows that build a hierarchy while preserving that hierarchy.

This cannot be done in one step. You need to first copy the rows and record the new and their matching old ids. Then you can update the references in the new rows to point to the new parents.

The simplest way to do this is using the MERGE statement:

```
 CREATE TABLE dbo.tst(id INT IDENTITY(1,1), parent_id INT, other INT);

 INSERT INTO dbo.tst(parent_id, other)VALUES(NULL,1);
 INSERT INTO dbo.tst(parent_id, other)VALUES(1,2);
 INSERT INTO dbo.tst(parent_id, other)VALUES(1,3);
 INSERT INTO dbo.tst(parent_id, other)VALUES(3,4);
 INSERT INTO dbo.tst(parent_id, other)VALUES(NULL,5);
 INSERT INTO dbo.tst(parent_id, other)VALUES(5,6);

 CREATE TABLE #tmp(old_id INT, new_id INT);

 MERGE dbo.tst AS trg
 USING dbo.tst AS src
 ON (0=1)
 WHEN NOT MATCHED 
 AND (src.id >= 1) --here you can put your own WHERE clause.
 THEN
 INSERT(parent_id, other)
 VALUES(src.parent_id, src.other)
 OUTPUT src.id, INSERTED.id INTO #tmp(old_id, new_id);

 UPDATE trg SET
   parent_id = tmp_translate.new_id
 FROM dbo.tst AS trg
 JOIN #tmp AS tmp_filter
 ON trg.id = tmp_filter.new_id
 JOIN #tmp AS tmp_translate
 ON trg.parent_id = tmp_translate.old_id;

 SELECT * FROM dbo.tst;
```

The line with the comment is the place where you can put your own where clause to select the rows that you want to copy. make sure to actually copy all referenced parents. If you copy a child without its parent the update will not catch it and it will point to the old parent in the end.

You also should wrap the MERGE and the UPDATE in a transaction to prevent someone else from reading the new and not yet finished records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT` to do this, you just need to manually specify the order of the columns. Here is an example, assuming that your table is called Product and that the ProductId is auto incremented. Notice that the first column returned in the `SELECT` is the primary key of the old row.

```
INSERT dbo.Product
SELECT
    ProductId,
    ArtNo,
    [Description]
    Specification,
    Unit,
    Account,
    NetPrice
    OhTime
FROM dbo.Product AS P
WHERE P.ParentId = 22
```

Does that help?

Comment: It could be more then one parent row to copy. And the ParentId should be the AutoId from the new rows.

Comment: You can change the `WHERE` clause to whatever you want, I just put in 22 because it was used as the example in the OP. You could also omit the `WHERE` clause entirely, it will still work the same.

Comment: The ParentId will be the AutoId from the new rows. The syntax is a little bit misleading, but while you are specifying the column name "ProductId" in the `SELECT` statement, you're referring to the ParentId column of the INSERT. Since the columns aren't specifically enumerated, the first column in the `SELECT` refers to the first column that isn't auto-incremented, which is ParentId. In other words, ParentId is getting populated with the previous ProductId.

Unless I'm confused and you are talking about updating the old rows?